# Crawler errors for unused URLs containing "mozekcdn-a.akamaihd.net"

Tags: google, url, googlebot, 404, crawl-errors

In the AdSense dashboard, Google is reporting crawl errors for unexpected URLs. It shows that Google crawler was unable to access some of my 87 pages. When I checked those pages I found that I haven't created those pages in my site. The pages have URLs like:

```
http//www.example.com/mozekcdn-a.akamaihd.net/mozekcdn-a.akamaihd.net/........../gsd.html?v=3&d=http//example.com
```

I am stunned to see something like `mozekcdn-a.akamaihd.net` automatically appended to my domain name. Does this mean that my server is infected? I am using self-hosted wordpress for my website.

Answer (score 1):

For a few days I have been getting the same requests.

I found [something in Polish](http://www.ball3d.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=7443). It indicates it might be a browser plugin  for malware, spyware, or some unknown purpose. I used Google Translate on that website.

[Another resource](https://www.comment-supprimer.com/mozekcdn-a-akamaihd-net/) is claiming it is adware.

Answer (score 1):

We're seeing a similar issue. It seems to have hit us on the 19th of December. I can see the traffic originated from Portugal and Turkey. Seems harmless enough.

[image: 404 spike]

We've had confirmation from Akamai that a 3rd party software program is installed on an end user's computer/device which was adding an unwanted string to URLs of the form `mozekcdn-a.akamaihd.net`. They informed the vendor and the software was patched on 21st Dec.