# Website pages being generated with mozekcdn-a.akamaihd.net; adware / malware?

Tags: google, malware

I have been getting crawl errors on Google Adsense on a number of pages, all ending in a peculiar suffix "mozekcdn-a.akamaihd.net".

For example

```
http://my-website.com/mozekcdn-a.akamaihd.net
http://my-website.com/mozekcdn-a.akamaihd.net/gsd.html
```

Now the strange thing is that such pages do not exist at all on my website. And all of a sudden the number of such pages being created has increased in the last 24 hours; all leading to a 404 Not found page.

Thus, trying to get to the bottom of this problem, I searched online, and came across some discussions on Stackexchange ([this link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74255/page-not-found-error-shows-a-url-which-really-does-not-exist-in-my-website-some)) and Google Groups ([this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/null-co-in/T863_Bkp_Ks)). It seems like some more websites are facing this problem, and the initial analysis is that this is some sort of malware / adware. A french website ([this link](https://www.comment-supprimer.com/mozekcdn-a-akamaihd-net/)) has given some more details, though I am not sure how authentic this is.

I am worried at the moment at the consequences of this issue. Will be great if any of you can check into it and suggest any possible solution.

Comment: This is mostly because of Ad. plugins in browser. It can be virus also. did you scan your site?

Comment: Yes, using the standard Sucuri scanner. How to identify which ad is causing the issue. I am using Google Adsense and Infolinks.

Comment: Ok , does scanner provided you any file paths in which there is malware? what status of site is according to scanner?

Comment: Nope. There was no such indication when I scanned using Sucuri. Showing the site to be clean.

Comment: okay then no need to worry about any malware..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not look like a problem for you to solve. It appears that **you do not** have malware, adware, or a virus on your system. You may not like these entries in your log of course. You can likely filter them in what ever software you use to analyze your web traffic.

This appears to be coming from your users as they access your site. It is thought to be an adware bug installed on the client computer that adds requests to each page accessed with various forms of mozekcdn-a.akamaihd.net in the URI. These always result in a 404.

I cannot figure out what the payoff would be and why this would be coded this way except that it might introduce new or more adware or viruses. I suspect that some of this will fade away as people update their anti-virus and anti-adware software, but some will remain for those who do not use these software or update them regularly.

Do keep tabs on your site just in case.

Comment: Thank you for informing! Though just in case any news comes up about this, please let me know here!

Comment: @anbose I have you in my answer list and if I come across anything new, I will update with new information and let you know.